# Specify XSRF config defaults for axios with webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, axios, webpacker

I'd like to specify config defaults that will be applied to every request:

```
// app/javascript/setupCSRFToken.js
import axios from 'axios'

export default function() {
  const csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name=csrf-token]").content
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = csrfToken
}

// app/javascript/packs/application.js
import setupCSRFToken from '../setupCSRFToken'
setupCSRFToken()
```

But it doesn't seem to be applied. Calling this in a React component (where axios is imported) just returns `undefined`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  console.log(axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'])
}
```